# Incorporate all columns of a dataframe into one regression

Tags: r

Lets say I have 50 columns in a `dataframe` and all of them should serve to explain variable y in the first column.. How do I achieve to incorporate them not separately into my regression model?

something like:

```
attach(data)
    lm(y~ columns[1:50])
```

I know the code is not true at all, but maybe you get what I mean
many thanks in advance,
Freddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `attach` use.  Here `.` signifies all the other columns

```
lm(y ~ ., data = data)
```

e.g. a reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)
```

---

Or another option is `reformulate` to construct the formula

```
lm(reformulate('.', response = 'mpg'), data = mtcars)
```